# Without internet connection local setup of Hadoop is not working

Tags: hadoop

I have set up hadoop in my laptop. I have following configurations:

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Problem is that, while my laptop is connected to internet, everything works fine, but while I disconnect it, job gets stuck throwing error like:

```
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable; Host Details : local host is: "EN-AbhishekM/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "192.168.0.101":49425;
```

I have set it up as single node cluster in my laptop, then how this issue is coming I don't have any clue.

EDIT: Following entries are there in my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost master slave slave1 slave2 slave3    localhost.localdomain
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

Comment: Please check your hosts file for correct mapping, it seems the localhost is not being resolved as expected.

Comment: Restart your hadoop-cluster when laptop not connected to the internet, once it get started you may connect your system back to internet.

Comment: @Mahendra it should work seamlessly irrespective of whether my machine is connected to internet or not.